# Show the word between first two commas from file with sed/grep

Tags: unix

I have file which contains below contents.

Threads: 14 total, 0 running, 14 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
//some more contents

I need to echo "0 running".

Does the sed/grep has parameters to achieve this ?

Comment: use `cut` or `awk` with `,` as delimiter...

Comment: If needed using this regex you will obtain the number of running threads

(?<=total\,\s)(.*)(?=\srunning\,)